# JavaScript Uglify is different and correct?

Tags: javascript, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have a uglified JS file where I want to get the beautified version and then uglify it with grunt again.
And I expect it to be the same as the first uglified file.

But when I do it one part, with the 'if', is different.

This is a part of the uglified file:

```
...function sendRequest(requestParams){if(Object.keys(requestParams).length>=1){$.ajax({type:"POST",url:VideoSearchUrl,data:requestParams,dataType:"xml"}).done(function(xmlDoc){buildResult($(xmlDoc)),responses++,requests==responses&&postSearchActions()})}}function...
```

But the uglified version from the beautified file look like this:

```
...function sendRequest(requestParams){Object.keys(requestParams).length>=1&&$.ajax({type:"POST",url:VideoSearchUrl,data:requestParams,dataType:"xml"}).done(function(xmlDoc){buildResult($(xmlDoc)),responses++,requests==responses&&postSearchActions()})}function...
```

Why is the 'if' dropped?
In an online uglifier it is still there.

Or does it mean the same?

Comment: You can see it's been replaced with an `&&` after the condition.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct due to [Short Circuit Evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation).

> As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, they are tested for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules:
>
> - false && (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to false.
> - true || (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to true.
>
> The rules of logic guarantee that these evaluations are always correct. **Note that the anything part of the above expressions is not evaluated**, so any side effects of doing so do not take effect. Also, note that the anything part of the above expression is any single logical expression (as indicated by the parentheses).

*(Emphasis by me)*

```js
a = 1;
b = 1;

if (a == b) {
  console.log(1);
}
// will log because it's like 
// (true) && expression
a == b && console.log(2);

// will NOT log because it's like 
// (false) && expression
a != b && console.log(3);
```

Why bother?

`true&&expression` is shorter than
`if(true){expression}` (every byte counts)

Comment: Thank you. So it would be the same. Is there a way to keep the 'if'?

Comment: If you can pass options through to uglifyjs, it's probably `-c conditionals=false` - https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#compress-options